# Not loading associations without proxies in NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate

I don't like the idea of proxy and lazy loading. I don't need that. I want pure POCO. And I want to control loading associations explicitly when I need.

Here is entity

```
public class Post
{
 public long Id { get; set; }
 public long OwnerId { get; set; }
 public string Content { get; set; }

 public User Owner { get; set; }
}
```

and mapping

```
<class name="Post">
    <id name="Id" />
    <property name="OwnerId" />
    <property name="Content" />
    <many-to-one name="Owner" column="OwnerId" />
</class>
```

However if I specify lazy="false" in the mapping, Owner is always eagerly fetched.
I can't remove many-to-one mapping because that also disables explicit loading or a query like

```
from x in session.Query<Post>()
where x.Owner.Title == "hello"
select x;
```

I specified lazy="true" and set use_proxy_validator property to false. But that also eager loads Owner.

Is there any way to load only Post entity?

Answer (score 0):

In short, it is not possible with out of box NH. But here is attempt at just, lazy loading without proxies

http://thinkbeforecoding.com/post/2009/02/07/Lazy-load-and-persistence-ignorance

Answer (score 0):

Set the class `User` to `lazy = false` on the mapping

```
<class name="User" table="Users" lazy="false">
```

Comment: No effect. Still eager loads Owner.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this property `<property name="OwnerId" />`... to get the owner id you can use `Owner.Id`. This will not trigger a lazy load. Owner will only be loaded if you hit any property besides the id. To make it a flat/simple POCO, you can use projections and ResultTransformers.

[Davy Brion - Must Everything be Virtual with NHibernate](http://davybrion.com/blog/2009/03/must-everything-be-virtual-with-nhibernate/)

Comment: If I don't make every member virtual all associations are eager loaded regardless of lazy load setting in the mapping. I want to load only Post entity without setting my member virtual.